# Почему вылазит ошибка при загрузке изображения с sfml?

Tags: sfml, c++

Пытаюсь в sfml загрузить изображение, но при запуске возникает такая вот ошибка: `Необработанное исключение в "0x60811f34" в "Dark_Silence.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x00211000".`.

Вот код:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(680, 200), "Dark Silence");

    Image heroimage; //создаем объект Image (изображение)
    heroimage.loadFromFile("images/hero.png");//загружаем в него файл

    Texture herotexture;//создаем объект Texture (текстура)
    herotexture.loadFromImage(heroimage);//передаем в него объект Image (изображения)

    Sprite herosprite;//создаем объект Sprite(спрайт)
    herosprite.setTexture(herotexture);//передаём в него объект Texture (текстуры)
    herosprite.setPosition(50, 25);

    while(window.isOpen()){
        Event ev;

        while(window.pollEvent(ev)){
            if(ev.type == Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(herosprite);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: В какой строчке крашится проект?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в том что не вызван метод setActive после создания RenderWindow.
Примерно так:

```
sf::ContextSettings contextSettings;
contextSettings.depthBits = 32;
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Window", sf::Style::Default, contextSettings);
//Activate or deactivate the window as the current target
///        for OpenGL rendering
window.setActive();
```

Проблема возможно возникла при создании OpenGL текстуры т.к. контекст не привязан к данному окну.

Answer (score 0):

1. В файл с ехе-файлом проекта надо закинуть sfml-graphics-d-2.dll файл. Он находится в папке bin программы SFML.
2. Укажи полный путь к файлу (С:/......), чтобы наверняка понимать, что ошибка устранена. Потом можно исправить на путь из корня проекта как у тебя.
   Код ниже, у меня работает:

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(640, 480), "Dark Silence");

    //Image heroimage; //создаем объект Image (изображение)
    //heroimage.loadFromFile("C:/Users/dmitriy/source/repos/2/Test/Test/x64/Debug/images/hero.png");//загружаем в него файл

    Texture herotexture;//создаем объект Texture (текстура)
    herotexture.loadFromFile("C:/Users/dmitriy/source/repos/2/Test/x64/Debug/1.png");//передаем в него объект Image (изображения)

    Sprite herosprite;//создаем объект Sprite(спрайт)
    herosprite.setTexture(herotexture);//передаём в него объект Texture (текстуры)
    herosprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 150, 50));
    herosprite.setPosition(50, 25);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(herosprite);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
```

`